# EF 6 SaveChanges() fails with Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table that is set to a varchar that cannot be null. Within my code, I am pulling the data from the database, updated the object and then completing a SaveChanges() on the connection.

This gives me the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FileReference', table
>   'dbo.Files'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

FileReference is populated, as I have checked, but within the exception I get:

Exception.Entries.source[0].Entity.FileReference is showing as null.

Confused on this one.

**Code as per request**

```
using (var conn = new MagmaContext())
{
    var result = from p in conn.Files
                 where p.fileId == 1
                 select p;

    var rec = result.FirstOrDefault();

    // code changed to use correct var
    rec.UpdateFileData(model);

    conn.SaveChanges();

}
```

I have an extension class called ObjectTransform.

```
public static class ObjectTransform
{

    public static File UpdateFileData(this File file, valueObject model)
    {
        file.FileReference = model.File.FileReference;
        file.LastUpdate = model.File.LastUpdate;
    }
}
```

And the viewmodel looks like this

```
public class valueObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public File File {get;set;}
}

public class File
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FileReference {get;set;}  
}
```

**Fixed Code as per comment**

Comment: Can you please include the code?

Comment: Make sure `FileReference` is not marked as database generated (`Identity` or `Computed`). Showing the entity model and configuration would help identifying the issue.

Comment: Is the column mapped in EF? Is there an empty string in there that's being optimized to a null value?

Comment: Did you actually check if the column in the DataBase allows null or not? Did you generate the DataBase with Code First approach?

Comment: Rick, I have just checked and the field is defined within the DAL

Comment: Rand, the database is set to not allow nulls for this field

Comment: Ivan, the field is not computed or an Identity field. It is also not a key of any sort

Comment: Did you try to set breakpoint on the setter of ``FileReference`` and have a look where the null is coming from?

Comment: Not sure if that is an error in your actual code but this ``ret.UpdateFileData(model);`` should be ``rec.UpdateFileData(model);`` (notice I changed the local variable from ``ret`` to ``rec``)

Comment: The exception indicates `INSERT` operation, so it definitely is not coming from the posted method.

Comment: Rand, sorry typo from my end.....fixed now

Comment: Rand, Breakpoint shows that the object rec does have the correct value set.

Comment: What is inside model?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all for all responses, but I came up with the solution. The reason was way simple in the end. All it was, the File object not initialised correctly. Hmm sorry, but worth a meantion anyways for other budding coders.